# Jquery style div and add title according to div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys i have a pretty standard div with css and i would like to append to a div that already exists with a given class. 
here is my mark up

```
<div id ="one" class="PortalBox">

     </div>

   <div class="ab_Box1d">
                <div style="width:600px;">
                    <%@ include file="./concur-reports/index.html"%> 
                </div>
    </div> <!--finish ab_box1d-->  


</div>
```

here is my jquery.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".PortalBox").each(function(){
    var ThisCss = $('<div class="ab_Box1a" id="report1" style="width:640px; padding-top:6px;">'+   
            '<div class="ab_Box1b" id="reportchild1"> </div>' +
                '<table class="ab_Box1c" width="100%" border="0"'+
                  'cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'+
              '<tr>'+
                  '<td style="text-align:left">Concur Reports</td>'+
              '</tr>'+
          '</table>'
   +
     '</div>' )
     ThisCss.insertAfter('.PortalBox');
   });
});
```

so basically I'm trying to append the markup in jquery when i stumble upon any div with class "PortalBox" however i need to make a part dynamic wich would basically be a title
this part

```
 '<td style="text-align:left">my channel</td>'+
```

need to be dynamic to pick up the title from another HTML attribute withing the div.
 can i add a "title" attribute to the div tag with a value and how do i make this possible with jquery? or java-script I'm open to any ideas so alternate solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the title in a `data-*` attribute:

```
<div data-title="my channel" class="PortalBox"></div>
```

You can then retrieve it with jQuery:

```
$('.PortalBox').data('title');
```

---

Here's the complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var report = $('<div class="ab_Box1a" style="width:640px; padding-top:6px;">'+   
        '<div class="ab_Box1b" ></div>' +
        '<table class="ab_Box1c" width="100%" border="0"'+
        'cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'+
        '<tr>'+
        '<td style="text-align:left">Concur Reports</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '</table>'+
        '</div>');

    $(".PortalBox").each(function() {
        report.clone()
            .find('td').text( $(this).data('title') )
            .appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

Please note that constructing HTML fragments like this is extremely error prone. If you find yourself doing this often, you should look into using a templating system.

Comment: Thanks for the response Joseph,thought your solution seems to work it for some reason overide my css? in other words it appears as though the style is not being picked up for that Title? Any ideas? and i would certainly look further into templating as well

Comment: @Miguel - I had removed the IDs from the markup, because you cannot reuse the same ID on different elements. You'll have to edit your CSS to target the class names.

Comment: Thanks but i was not applying styles by id. in other words it not picking up the styles from the class="ab_Box1c". this is my last question I promise sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: @Miguel - Then you either have some styles overriding it, or your selector does not simply target `.ab_Box1c`. Either way, this is beyond the scope of this question, and there's no way to answer that without looking through the whole code base.

Comment: Thanks again joseph but ill leave  you with this the last step basically removes '<table class="ab_Box1c" width="100%" border="0"' ill figuered it out. Thanks for the reply Im a bit closer to getting this to work the way i wanted. Miguel

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div selector').attr('title', enterDesiredvalue);
```

Comment: Don't know what you're after but actually the `title` attribute is a tooltip in HTML. So @Joseph's way is better actually